# 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file after adding to PATH

Tags: java, javacc

for my coursework we are dealing with javacc. My professor sent us a javacc zip file and followed the set up guide, what i done:

- Unzipped file
- coppied the bin directory
- added it to the PATHS on system variable

when i try to test my code working with javacc i get error:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: how is this related to compiler construction?

Comment: related to what now?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click **Computer**

Click the **properties**

On the left pane select **Advanced System Setting**s

Select **Environment Variables**

Under the System Variables, 
Select **PATH** and click **edit**,
and then click new and add path as C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin (depending on your installation path)
and finally click ok

Next restart your command prompt and open it and try javac

Comment: I dont really see what is different in that description to what OP described as the instructions he followed. Or did he just forget to restart the cmd?

Comment: The difference is that the student put JavaCC's bin directory on the path.  The answer is to also put the jdk bin directory on the path as well.